# Need a RegEx guru

Tags: regex, glossary

I'm trying to write a script that parses a block of HTML and matches words against a given glossary of terms. If it finds a match, it wraps the term in `<a class="tooltip"></a>` and provides a definition.

It's working okay -- except for two major shortcomings:

1. It matches text that is in attributes
2. It matches text that is already in an `<a>` tag, created a nested link.

Is there any way to have my regular expression match only words that are not in attributes, and not in `<a>` tags?

Here's the code I'm using, in case it's relevant:

```
foreach(Glossary::map() as $term => $def) {
  $search[] = "/\b($term)\b/i";
  self::$lookup[strtoupper($term)] = $def;
}

return preg_replace_callback($search, array(&$this,'replace'),$this->content);
```

Comment: Here comes the "Don't do that with a regex" answers...

Comment: Edit: That should read "not in A tags".. the HTML got stripped out. It's okay if the text appears in any tag other than an anchor tag.

Comment: I fixed up the code blocks. When you have inline HTML that you want to have show up, surround with with backticks: `

Comment: Don’t do that with a regex. Use some markup to mark the terms and just replace the marked terms with your links (with a parser).

Comment: And to actually answer the question, NO there's no such regular expression.

Answer (score 5):

"Don't do that with a regex."

Use an HTML parser, then apply a regex to the contents of HTML elements as it identifies them.  That will allow you to easily operate on lots of different variants of HTML structure, valid and otherwise, without a lot of cruft and hard-to-maintain regular expressions.

[Robust and Mature HTML Parser for PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/292926)

Comment: How did you link to another question on StackOverflow regarding this issue and not link to this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454?

Comment: How did you like to anything without linking to: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/001311.html

Comment: @Jason Because amusing as it may be, it doesn't actually help the OP accomplish anything.

Answer (score 3):

Personally, I prefer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454).

Answer (score 0):

HTML parsing is an interesting research topic. What do you mean with HTML? There are standards (quite a few), and there are web pages. Most researchers do not use regular expressions to parse HTML